# My Galera Cluster does not connect across AWS regions

Tags: mariadb, aws, galera

- I am building a MariaDB Galera Cluster, on AWS, EC2. Using MariaDB 10.5 and Galera 4.
- I have two nodes in the California region, named **galera_ca** and **galera_ca2**, and a third node in Oregon name **galera_or**
- The security groups between the servers are wide open, and the ping time between OR and CA is 12ms
- I started **galera_ca** using **galera_new_cluster**
- I started **galera_ca2** using **systemctl start mariadb**

The two California nodes connect and share data just fine. 
**wsrep_cluster_size** indicates that I have two nodes in the cluster.

- I started **galera_or** using **systemctl start mariadb**

Oregon then hangs on starting for a very long time, and **wsrep_cluster_size** shows three nodes, but the server cannot be connected to.

Eventually **systemctl start mariadb** returns this message: 
*Job for mariadb.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*

**systemctl status mariadb.service** doesn't show anything exceptional,

**journalctl -xe** shows: 
*requested state transfer from '*any*', but it is impossible to select State Transfer donor: Resource temporarily unavailable*

**wsrep_cluster_size** still shows three nodes, but mariadb is not running in OR. 
If I try to shut down either of the California servers **systemctl stop mariadb** it never returns.

All three servers have basically the same configuration:

```
[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so

wsrep_node_name='galera_ca'
wsrep_node_address="INTERNAL ADDRESS OF THIS NODE"

wsrep_cluster_name='galera-experiment'
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://EXTERNAL ADDRESS OF NODE CA, EXTERNAL ADDRESS OF NODE CA2, EXTERNAL ADDRESS OF NODE OR"

wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=300M; gcache.page_size=300M"
wsrep_slave_threads=4
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

If I try just one CA node and the OR node, the result is the same.

Comment: AWS does a lot to obviate the need for Galera.  However, I do not have enough details to make that case.

Comment: That's not true, AWS does not provide cross-region read/write cluster

Answer (score 1):

In wsrep_node_address on Amazon EC2, you must use the global DNS name, instead of the internal IP address.